# Setting a password input programmatically c#

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, facebook

I am trying to fill login information from textboxes.
I have:

```
WebBrowser1.Navigate("http://facebook.com/login.php");
//...
WebBrowser1.Document.All("email").InnerText = TextBox1.Text;
WebBrowser1.Document.All("pass").InnerText = TextBox2.Text;
//...
```

This generally works, but for facebook login it doesn't. It won't set value of "pass", it  sets, from what I can tell, the value of placeholder.  Why? And more importantly how to make it work. Thanks.

Edit:
Ok, As soon I posted this, I tried:

```
WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("pass").SetAttribute("value", TextBox2.Text)
```

and it works. But I still wonder why the above line with InnerText doesn't?

Comment: did you read the following links [WebBrowser.Document Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.document(v=vs.110).aspx)  and https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.htmldocument.getelementbyid(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: What are you trying to do? You are aware that scraping Facebook is not allowed?